# Field 'T' not found in table (in BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT ROUND(INTEGER(field)/64, 0)*64 as T, 
COUNT(T) FROM [table] GROUP BY T;
```

But it gives me a:

```
Field 'T' not found in table
```

What am I doing wrong? Must be trivial but I don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `COUNT(*)` instead:

```
SELECT ROUND(INTEGER(field)/64, 0)*64 as T, COUNT(*)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY T;
```

The issue is the use of the column alias in the `SELECT`, not the `GROUP BY`.  This should work in both legacy and standard SQL, although I strongly recommend the latter.

Comment: Ooof. Thanks. I'm very much inclined to say "sorry" at this point :S

Comment: Note: It _is_ possible to use an alias in `GROUP BY` with Big Query, q.v. here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql